# Wordpress Elementor. My custom HTML did not render

Tags: html, wordpress, mailchimp, elementor

I got a custom email signup form from Mailchimp and implemented it on my wordpress website with elementor custom HTML, it kinda works but the problem is that when i log off my wordpress session and check the website as a visitor, the custom HTML gets written as a text instead of being read as a html file and also some tags get ignored such as **style** , **form** , **input**  and **script**

Everything is getting saved to the database, it just doesn't read the code as it should. I purged all cache several times.

This the code i'm trying to insert and make it stay when im logged off

```html
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->

<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-071822.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;  width:100%;}

    /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */

</style>




<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="https://gmail.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9eedbcb189ca63a07ad3fc7e8&amp;id=96681ba87c&amp;f_id=00546ae0f0" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_self">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
        
 
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Seu melhor email:  
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required>
    <span id="mce-EMAIL-HELPERTEXT" class="helper_text"></span>
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear foot">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9eedbcb189ca63a07ad3fc7e8_96681ba87c" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        <div class="optionalParent">
            <div class="clear foot">
                <input type="submit" value="Garantir meu lugar" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

[image]
**Logged in**

[image]**Logged out**

Comment: Could be a cache problem, Purge the cache then test the page on incognito mode or a different browser.

Comment: Done but the it stills the same, I've seen a guy with the same problem as me, I don't think  it's a cache related problem. Can I provide any other info that could possibly help?

Comment: As you clearly mentioned problem happens when you logout then it could be only because of the cache, Cache comes from your cache plugin, if the server has any cache options, if you're using any CDN that cache your pages, and your browser itself.
You will have to purge the cache from the plugin, your server, and cdn as well, then you need to clear your browser cache, Or you can enable the **Disable Cache** option on the chrome dev tools that you'll find in the Network tab.
If you have done all these things correctly then you need to check what data is stored in Database after your changes.

Comment: I cleared cache with W3 Total Cache by using the "Purge All Caches" option and disabled Chrome cache. I'm not sure it cleared every cache including CDN or server so I need to find a way to clear both. Also how could i check the Database after my changes?

Comment: 1. if your changed content is showing while editing the post using elementor then changes are being saved to the database for sure.
2. But if you need to check the values in the database, then you need to check the `wp_posts` table in phpmyadmin and search the row by post `ID` and then check `post_content` value, however, you don't need to do it if you can see the edited content showing on the edit page. Clearing all the cache and Force Reload should solve your issue for sure.

Comment: My changed content is getting saved to the database, but only the mailchimp html isn't for some reason.

The problem isn't that the content is saving or not, but the mailchimp html that doesn't get read by the server.

I cleared all the cache and tried to force reload by using a plugin called Force Refresh, but it didn't solve it at all.